# Solr facet with an extra filter (parent levels)

Tags: solr, facet

Simple solr query to see alternative options instead of city of "New York".

```
&facet.field={!ex=CityTag}City&fq={!tag=CityTag}City:"NewYork"&rows=0
```

I want to be able to get cities which are in defined region/state :
So I want to add an extra filter/criteria to determine my facets and the extra filter is not for result set.

something like this :

```
&facet.field={!ex=CityTag **filter=Region:blabla** }City&fq={!tag=CityTag}City:"NewYork"&rows=0
```

is something like this possible ?